# ¿por que no me cargan los valores del css en mi index?

Tags: javascript, html, css

este es mi index.

```css
*{ margin:0 auto; width: 960px; }

p{ color:red; }

body{ background-color: #FAF8EF; color: #776E65; font-size: 16px; }

#tiempo{ padding: 5px; margin: 2px; border-radius: 2px; border-style:solid; height: 40px; width: 80px; display: block; }

minutos{

padding: 5px;

}

segundos{

padding: 5px; }

tablero .row{

padding: 0px; width: 100%; }

tablero .row .celda{

margin:1px; padding:0px; height:80px; width:80px; display: inline-block; position:relative; border-style:solid; }

tablero .row .celda:hover{

background-color: blue; }

tablero .row .celda img {

width: 100%; height: 100px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }

.rojo{ background-color:red; } .amarillo{ background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="ES">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
    <title>
      El Triki
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
      </nav>
      </header>
      <section>
        <article>
          <div id="tiempo">
            <p>Contador:</p>
            <p id="contador"></p>
            <span id="minutos">00</span>:
            <span id="segundos">00</span>
          </div>

          <div id="tablero">
          <div class="row">

        <div id="c00" onClick="RevisarCelda(0,0)" class="celda amarillo"></div>
        <div id="c01" onClick="RevisarCelda(0,1)" class="celda rojo"></div>
        <div id="c02" onClick="RevisarCelda(0,2)" class="celda amarillo"></div>
      </div><!--row-->

      <div id="c10" onClick="RevisarCelda(1,0)" class="celda amarillo"></div>
      <div id="c11" onClick="RevisarCelda(1,1)" class="celda rojo"></div>
      <div id="c12" onClick="RevisarCelda(1,2)" class="celda amarillo"></div>
    </div><!--row-->

    <div id="c20" onClick="RevisarCelda(2,0)" class="celda amarillo"></div>
    <div id="c21" onClick="RevisarCelda(2,1)" class="celda rojo"></div>
    <div id="c22" onClick="RevisarCelda(2,2)" class="celda amarillo"></div>

        </article>
      </section>
      <aside>
      </aside>
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: cual es el problema exactamente.

Comment: Disculpa pero no marcaste una respuesta o indicaste mas información nadie te la resolvió?

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer en esta parte:

```
<div id="tablero>">
```

Esta demás un signo de mayor , dice tablero> , y creo que es únicamente tablero, así:

`<div id="tablero">`

Espero te sirva :)

Answer (score 0):

Tu código css necesita estar bien escrito mira cuando escribes "`tablero`" en tu código css no tiene el numeral o llamado gato es decir "#", es por esa razón que no se interpreta ahora te dejo el código corregido.

```
*{ margin:0 auto; width: 960px; }

p{ color:red; }

body{ background-color: #FAF8EF; color: #776E65; font-size: 16px; }

#tiempo{ padding: 5px; margin: 2px; border-radius: 2px; border-style:solid; height: 40px; width: 80px; display: block; }

minutos{

padding: 5px;

}

segundos{

padding: 5px; }

#tablero .row{

padding: 0px; width: 100%; }

#tablero .row .celda{

margin:1px; padding:0px; height:80px; width:80px; display: inline-block; position:relative; border-style:solid; }

#tablero .row .celda:hover{

background-color: blue; }

#tablero .row .celda img {

width: 100%; height: 100px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }

.rojo{ background-color:red; } .amarillo{ background-color:yellow; }
```